# Make a Google Docs link that makes a copy and automatically shares it into a shared folder?

Tags: google-docs

I want a user to share a URL to a Google Doc. When another user follows the link, they must make a copy and that copy is available in a shared folder. Are their parameters I can add to the URL to do this?

The users are students and teachers. Users share the same Google Workspace domain. The students have major digital literacy gaps so any steps I can remove to sharing to their teachers is significant.

Answer (score 3):

Given the url of your google docs file, you need to replace `edit` with `copy` and use `&copyDestination=[Drive_FolderID]` (optional) to redirect the copied file to a specific folder.

As for the share to a shared folder, I can't find any parameter for it. The `copyDestination` might still work in your case.

#### From:

- [https://docs.google.com/document/d/[Doc_FileID]/edit?resourcekey=[Resource_Key]](https://docs.google.com/document/d/%5BDoc_FileID%5D/edit?resourcekey=%5BResource_Key%5D)

#### To:

- [https://docs.google.com/document/d/[Doc_FileID]/copy?resourcekey=[Resource_Key]&copyDestination=[Drive_FolderID]](https://docs.google.com/document/d/%5BDoc_FileID%5D/copy?resourcekey=%5BResource_Key%5D&copyDestination=%5BDrive_FolderID%5D)

After confirming to "**Make a copy**", it opens the copied file and will show on the Drive folder.

#### Output:

[image: output]