# Get Google script to work in multiple sheets within a workbook

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet and script that allow multiple items to be selected from a dropdown list. The sheet is:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PpHu08pP_lbj3MErWsLUKV_Y4C-E52Hsld7DqhM9gXY/edit?usp=sharing  .

I am using this script:

```
    function onEdit(e) {
var oldValue;
var newValue;
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();
if(activeCell.getColumn() >= 3 && activeCell.getRow() >= 1) {
newValue=e.value;
oldValue=e.oldValue;
if(!e.value) {
activeCell.setValue("");
}
else {
if (!e.oldValue) {
activeCell.setValue(newValue);
}
else {
activeCell.setValue(oldValue+', '+newValue);
}
}
}
}
```

The options for the drop down are: apple, orange, banana, peach.
Right now, the script only works for Sheet2. I would like the script to work for any sheet I may add to the workbook. For instance, the script works and allows the user to select apple and banana, for instance, in Sheet2, but the script does not work for Sheet3. In Sheet3, the user can select apple or banana, but not both.
The correct results are allowing the user to select multiple options from the drop down menu in a cell. This happens in Sheet 2. The incorrect results is allowing only one option to be selected from the drop down menu; this is happening in Sheet 3.

I have tried explicitly stating which tabs to use in row 6 using OR statements, but that didn't work in Sheet3. It did still allow for multiple selections in the dropdown in Sheet2.
This also didn't easily allow for expansion of the workbook.
I also tried some suggestions using triggers, but that didn't provide the desired results, either.
I have searched for this issue online and in StackOverflow, but I can't find a solution to allowing for multiple sheets to run off of the same script.

Suggestions and modifications to the script would be quite welcome.
I am a novice to this, so while I can read the code and figure out what it is saying, I really can't generate new code to fix what I want.

Comment: SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()

Comment: all functions in all projects contained in a spreadsheet can access all or any of the sheets. But I would recommend that you get away from using getActive or setActive.  It's a remnant of the macro world and my guess is that like me most of the volunteers here don't even like to read that code because it's to hard to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Your question must stand alone; please don't assume that users must/can/should/will open your spreadsheet to better understand your question or your data. This information needs to be included (and explained) in the body of your question; you also need to include an example of a successful outcome. Would you please edit your question to include this information in a text table.

Comment: BTW, your spreadsheet link requires a request for access. This is a disincentive for users; you should either give access to anyone with the link, or change the url to force users to make their own copy so that your original is not compromised. [Instrunction guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67537180/1330560)

Comment: Edited to address the last two comments by @Tedinoz above.

Comment: `In Sheet3, the user can select apple or banana, but not both` The you don't need `onEdit` for Sheet3. Just use conventional Data validation with only two options (Apple & Banana).

Comment: `The options for the drop down [in Sheet2] are: apple, orange, banana, peach.` Well, no, you specified a range from sheet=`Parameters` that lists "Apple, Banana, Oranges, Kiwi, Grapes"

Comment: `The incorrect results is allowing only one option to be selected from the drop down menu; this is happening in Sheet 3.` But that is because: 1) you said the user can select apple or banana, but not both, and 2), you set `Advanced Options, if the data is invalid, reject input`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to apply an onEdit function to multiple separate ranges in google sheets Apps Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73680582/is-there-a-way-to-apply-an-onedit-function-to-multiple-separate-ranges-in-google)